# Setting a property in QML from python

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I am trying to grab a string from a python function back to QML.  It seems to work on a simple Text item below, where the '`value`' property is taken from the python function `MyDB.getIncome()`.  This works fine.  But when I use the same functionality but to populate a property for a `ListElement`, it doesnt seem to work.

The first main.qml below works fine.

The second main.qml attached is the one that wont work. If you want to try if everything else works just comment out  'property string value: myDB.getIncome()' and assign it some value

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, pyqtProperty, QVariant
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView



class MyDB(QObject):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()

        @pyqtSlot(result=str)
        def getIncome(self):
                return "testing income"


## Main Function
if __name__ == '__main__':
        myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

        appLabel = QQuickView()
        mydb = MyDB()
        appLabel.rootContext().setContextProperty("myDB", mydb)
        appLabel.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))

        appLabel.show()

        myApp.exec_()
        sys.exit()
```

main.qml (works okay)

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 250; height: 450
    color: "gray"

    Text {
        id: exp

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: 'dark red'
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 18

        property string value: myDB.getIncome()

        text: value
    }

}
```

main.qml (not working)

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 250; height: 450
    color: "white"

    ListModel {
        id: mainModel

        ListElement {
            name: "Money"

            //property string value: 3
            property string value: myDB.getIncome()

        }

        ListElement {
            name: "Total Expenses"
            property string value: 4
        }

        ListElement {
            name: "Total Income"
            property string value: 56
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: mainDelegate
        Item {
            width: 100; height: 100
            scale: PathView.iconScale

            Image {
                id: myIcon
                y: 20; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                source: icon
            }
            Text {
                anchors { top: myIcon.bottom; horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
                font.pixelSize: 18
                text: name + ": " + value
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: appHighlight
        Rectangle { width: 130; height: 10; color: "lightsteelblue" }
    }

    PathView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        highlight: appHighlight
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
        focus: true
        model: mainModel
        delegate: mainDelegate
        path: Path {
            startX: root.width/2
            startY: 0
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.5 }
            PathLine { x: root.width/2; y: root.height*0.4; }
            PathPercent { value: 0.48; }
            PathLine { x: root.width/2; y: root.height*0.5; }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1.0 }
            PathLine { x: root.width/2; y: root.height*0.6; }
            PathPercent { value: 0.52; }
            PathLine { x: root.width/2; y: root.height; }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.5 }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're going down the wrong path, which is your goal to maybe give you a better approach.

Comment: So what is the better approach?

Comment: I could not say it now because you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/),  you are focusing on solving a possible solution that you have no certainty that works, and not the main problem, what is your main objective? What are you going to use the ListModel for?